# better way to store long SQL strings in C#

Tags: c#, sql

I have searched around for a while for this and have not found anything.

I am storing some pretty long SQL select strings (a shorter one like this:)

```
      string mySelectQuery = "select distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no as stop_unique_id_no,distribution_line_items.unique_id_no as line_unique_id_no, stop_name, stop_address,route_code AS RouteCode, customer_reference," +
            "distribution_line_items.datetime_created, rma_number from distribution_stop_information join distribution_line_items on " +
            "distribution_line_items.unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no " +
            "where distribution_line_items.datetime_created > '2/22/2017' and customer_no = '91000'";
```

then passing them by

```
var Ourstops = (List<stop_data>)db.Query<stop_data>(mySelectQuery);
```

This is cumbersome and produces hard to read/debug code.

What are some better ways of doing this?

Just a point of clairification - on this project I am not allowed to create any sprocs.  Strictly a query only use type, and using postgresql (not that that matters that much here)

Comment: Create stored procedure in sql side and call from c#

Comment: I agree with @AkashKC about the stored procedure. I'm not sure if this is an option for you; however, this would really be beneficial in multiple ways. Especially if there are any concerns of SQL injection.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is my preferred formatting, just one guy's opinion:

```
string mySelectQuery = @"
    select 
        distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no as stop_unique_id_no
        ,distribution_line_items.unique_id_no as line_unique_id_no, stop_name
        ,stop_address,route_code AS RouteCode, customer_reference
        ,distribution_line_items.datetime_created, rma_number 
    from 
        distribution_stop_information 
        join distribution_line_items on distribution_line_items.unique_id_no = distribution_stop_information.unique_id_no
    where 
        distribution_line_items.datetime_created > '2/22/2017' and customer_no = '91000'
";
```

Benefits

- Copy and paste right into sql management studio
- Using the @ (verbatim literal) eliminates all the quotes and concatenations
- Easy to also use $ for string interpolation
- commas in front make commenting lines out easier

But do be mindful of SQL Injection and use parameters as much as possible- which is pretty much always. (Edit from comments)

Comment: Are you using the space bar to line things up or how are you doing that?

Comment: just using tab, tab tab, and sometimes tab tab tab :-)

Comment: you can always put in a view or sproc as the others mentioned, but those can start to build up on you too... could have hundreds and hundreds of items... just go for sanity and a sense of order

Comment: *Easy to also use $ for string interpolation*. That smells like a SQL injection vulnerability just waiting to happen.

Comment: @DanielMann, yes certainly, good point! If you are interpolating user input then watch out!... but not an issue if just bringing different string chunks together or with developer supplied input (unless the developer is trying to sql inject themselves)

Comment: @travis.js Even if it is only used for known safe input, using parameters also gives you the benefit of allowing SQL Server to use cached query plans to decrease the time it takes to get you results.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain awesome! that is great info for everyone to know; I upvoted both you and DanielMann

Comment: simple and just what I was looking for...liked the string interpolation version with $@"select....{variable}";

Comment: @JoeRuder great, glad to help... just watch out for SQL Injection... don't put any unparameterized user input in the sql string

Comment: Concerning the SQL injection, good point but I still cannot figure out how to use parameters correctly in this use case.  I have another question open but few answers so far:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42440187/using-parameters-with-dapper

Comment: This is golden! Thanks! And don't forget to use the `DynamicParameters`!

Comment: This has changed my life. Thank you @travis.js

Answer (score 4):

- Stored procs or views (SQL specific)
- Resources
- Use of @ to allow line breaks
- Configuration files
- Content management system (if you have one, and even then not too sure about that)
- Entity Framework so you don't have SQL (I'm not a fan BTW.  I'd go SPs)

Answer (score 3):

My favourite question! Like you perhaps, I find SQL in string literals the weirdest thing in programming. So weird that I went off and wrote [QueryFirst](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bbsimonbb.QueryFirst), a visual studio extension for working intelligently with SQL. Your SQL lives in a .sql file, like god intended. You edit it with the marvellous TSQL editor, connected to the database with intellisense for tables and columns and syntax validation. Every time you save the file, QueryFirst checks that the query runs, then (re)generates the C# wrapper that lets you use it. Behind the scenes, QueryFirst compiles your SQL into the binary, and accesses it with GetManifestResourceStream. All your data access is continually integration tested and working, and you have no more SQL hanging around in string literals.

Comment: I had already looked at QueryFirst (I dig the music behind the video btw) -- any idea on if using it with postgresql and either the dotconnect or npgsql driver works?

Comment: You already looked ! Knock me over with a feather ! I'm so busy getting folk's attention, it never occured to me they might find it on their own. For Postgres, just specify providerName="Npgsql" in your QfDefaultConnection. If you want type safety for your input parameters, you need to append the [DbType](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with an underscore to the parameter name. So in your sql for example `select * from users where userid = @myUser_Int32`. Let me know how you get on - Postgres support is still wet.

Comment: And in your QfRuntimeConnection.GetConnection(), you return a NpgsqlConnection. Talking of reducing moving parts, QueryFirst is not a dependency, it's a code generation tool, so it should be very transparent. Nothing to it. You should have a fine time.

Comment: How about if I use the dotConnect from Devart?  I use both in different projects depending:  https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/postgresql/

Comment: That should work, but not without a bit of tweaking. Currently, we generate some provider-specific code for creating parameters, but now that you ask, this could all be done via standard ADO interfaces with no provider-dependent calls. Can you leave it with me for the weekend?

Comment: Does this work with the SQLite ADO implementations (System.Data.SQLite or CsharpSqlite) and if not are there plans to implement SQLite compatibility in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered getting rid of the strings by using a query builder? There are heaps around eg. https://github.com/cdroulers/awesome-sql-builder.

I have never used it so cannot comment on it specifically.

And even if you don't want to go the heavy EF ORM route you might also look at something like https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper and avoid constructing SQL by hand.

Aside from it being a potential security risk the hassle in terms of getting quoting right is worth the time and effort investing in a micro ORM.

Comment: The point of Dapper is to let you construct your SQL by hand. And Dapper does nothing to help you get your sql out of string literals. All the Dapper examples I've seen have SQL in quotes.

Comment: I have thought about and looked at some of these, the biggest fear is statements like "Supports all basic SQL operations for PostgreSQL" -- from the link you mentioned.  What features does it not support and am I going to be spending hours debugging something that turns out to be caused by yet another addin?  I try and reduce as many moving parts as possible, but that is a good idea.  And Dapper does not help in this instance (great micro ORM however, I do use it).

Comment: @user1585345 The point of recommending Dapper is to avoid constructing SQL by hand entirely and use LINQ. The benefit of it being that it requires less overhead than EF. The point being to avoid constructing SQL by hand because it is laborious, error prone and a security risk.

Comment: @JoeRuder If it does not support a feature then you drop back down to what you are doing now which is creating the string yourself. Another interesting approach can be found here http://maxtoroq.github.io/DbExtensions/. As always Google is your friend. As for moving parts - yes a trade off but I think changing the manual construction with something else is a no brainer. Or if you feel that you don't want to rely on someone elses code then write a builder yourself, it would not take a huge amount of effort.

Comment: We're not going to agree, but I'd like to understand! You use linq to generate sql for dapper? How does that work? Can you point me to a blog post or some sample code or something?

Comment: No I use LINQ with Dapper - No hard coded SQL anywhere.